# Run a job on all nodes of Sun Grid Engine cluster, only once

Tags: cluster-computing, job-scheduling, sungridengine, qsub

I want to run a job on all the active nodes of a 64 node Sun Grid Engine Cluster, scheduled using qsub. I am currently using array-job variable for the same, but sometimes the program is scheduled multiple times on the same node.

```
qsub -t 1-64:1 -S /home/user/.local/bin/bash program.sh
```

Is it possible to schedule only one job per node, on all nodes parallely?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a parallel environment. Create a parallel environment with :

```
qconf -ap "parallel_environment_name"
```

and set "allocation_rule" to 1, which means that all processes will have to reside on  different hosts. Then when submitting your array job, specify your the number of nodes you want to use with your parallel environment. In your case :

```
qsub -t 1-64:1 -pe "parallel_environment_name" 64 -S /home/user/.local/bin/bash program.sh
```

For more information, check these links: http://linux.die.net/man/5/sge_pe and [Configuring a new parallel environment](https://blogs.oracle.com/templedf/entry/configuring_a_new_parallel_environment) at [DanT's Grid Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/templedf/) (link no longer working; there are copies on [the wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20131215061314/https://blogs.oracle.com/templedf/entry/configuring_a_new_parallel_environment) and [softpanorama](http://www.softpanorama.org/HPC/Grid_engine/parallel_environment.shtml#Important_details)).

Answer (score 0):

I you have a bash terminal, you can run

```
for host in $(qhost | tail -n +4 | cut -d " " -f 1); do qsub -l hostname=$host program.sh; done
```

- "-l hostname=" specifies on which host to run the job.
- The for loop iterates over the result returned by qstat to take each node and call the command specifying the host to use.

Comment: Doesn't work out. The scheduler is doing its own thing. Printed the $HOSTNAME in each program outfile. This is what I get:
    node005.local
node005.local
node010.local
node011.local
node021.local
node023.local
node028.local
node038.local
node049.local
node054.local
node003.local
node028.local
node006.local
node023.local
node019.local
node059.local
node022.local
node058.local
node011.local
node005.local
node048.local
node038.local
node049.local
I think I need to also explicitly mention processors per node?

Comment: Hum it works for me... I don't know why you get those prints. Which version os SGE are you using? Maybe it differs with mine. And no, you don't need to mention processors per node.